# UnitTest against Firebase ensure callback is fired

Tags: android, unit-testing, firebase, mockito, firebase-authentication

I'm fairly new to android & java. I'm trying to write a unit test that verifies that Firebase method is called with correct parameters & that specific call back is fired on success

```
public class RegistrationViewModel {

private iRegistrationViewCallback viewCallback;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
public  String email;
public String password;

public RegistrationViewModel(iRegistrationViewCallback view, FirebaseAuth mockAuth) {
    viewCallback = view;
    mAuth = mockAuth;
}

public void createUser() {

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener((Executor) this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    viewCallback.doSomething();
                }
            });

}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

My Unit test looks like this:

```
public class RegistrationViewModelUnitTest {

private RegistrationViewModel viewModelUnderTest;
private iRegistrationViewCallback mockView;
private FirebaseAuth mockAuth;


@Before
public void SetUp() {
    mockView = mock(iRegistrationViewCallback.class);
    mockAuth = mock(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getClass());
    viewModelUnderTest = new RegistrationViewModel(mockView,mockAuth);
}

@Test
public void progressBarIsDismissedWhenRegistrationIsSuccessFul() throws Exception {
    String email = "somusername";
    String password = "somePassword";
    viewModelUnderTest.email = email;
    viewModelUnderTest.password = password;
    viewModelUnderTest.createUser();
    verify(mockAuth).createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
    verify(mockView).doSomething();
}

}
```

`verify(mockView).doSomething();` obviously fails.

What would be the best way to verify that `viewCallback.doSomething();` is called on success. Should I somehow stub the `onComplete`? or is there a different way of doing this? I have thought of putting Firebase code behind an interface but still cant figure out how to verify that the call back is fired.
I'm using Mockito for mocking.

Comment: can you add the implementation of createUserWithEmailAndPassword method?

Comment: also, is FirebaseAuth a singleton?

Comment: That is part of the firebase sdk as far as i can tell the code is not publicly available. 
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: If you are mocking the FirebaseAuthentication singleton, you won't get any callbacks from it, unless you arrange for that yourself as a behavior of the mock.  You'll have to say what happens in response to calling createUserWithEmailAndPassword.  You do that with the `when` function in Mockito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems more like an intergration test scenario.

If you want to unit test it i would do the following:

**Step 1)**

Create a public class with the callback behavior, instead of using an anonymous class:

```
public class MyOnCompleteListener implements OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
          viewCallback.doSomething();
      }
});
```

**Step 2)**

Change your createUser method to:

```
public void createUser() {

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener((Executor) this
                       , new MyOnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() );

}
```

**Step 3)**

Define your test as follows:

```
@Test
public void progressBarIsDismissedWhenRegistrationIsSuccessFul() throws Exception {
    String email = "somusername";
    String password = "somePassword";
    viewModelUnderTest.email = email;
    viewModelUnderTest.password = password;

    Task taskMock = mock(Task.class);
    when(mockAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword (email, password)).thenReturn(taskMock);

    viewModelUnderTest.createUser();
    verify(mockAuth, times(1)).createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
    verify(taskMock, times(1)).addOnCompleteListener(any(RegistrationViewModel.class)
          , any(MyOnCompleteListener.class));
}
```

The bottom line is that your verify that a certain callback is registered for the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method.

Thats all you can do if you want to have this as a unit test without any actual invocation of framework code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment I manged to find a working solution using your sample code above :)